# JAXB "If a class has @XmlElement property, it cannot have @XmlValue property."

Tags: java, xml, xml-serialization, jaxb

I am trying to define XML to Java object binding using JAXB. Everything works fine except when I am trying to **produce** XML like **this**:

```xml
<request>
    Get Price
    <sessionId>read-only</sessionId>
</request>
```

**from** object which class defined like **this**:

```java
@XmlRootElement(name="request")
public class  Request {

    @XmlValue
    public String getCommandID() { return "Get Price"; };

    @XmlElement
    public String getSessionID() { return "read-only"; };

}
```

I am getting the following exception:

```
If a class has @XmlElement property, it cannot have @XmlValue property.
```

If I would change the "sessionId" element to be an attribute, everything works fine, but of course I want it to be an Element.

I thought JAXB is supposed to be very flexible, I am sure I'm missing something obvious.

Could you help?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The type of XML document that you are looking to map is referred to as having "mixed content".  The corresponding XML schema would look like the following:

```
<xs:element name="request">
    <xs:complexType mixed="true">
        <xs:sequence>
            <xs:element name="sessionId" type="xs:string"/>
        </xs:sequence>
    </xs:complexType>
</xs:element>
```

This means that text nodes can appear mixed in with the element nodes.  While the rules for converting your sample document appear trivial, the following document would also be valid and the rules are less clear.

```
<request>
    Get Price
    <sessionId>read-only</sessionId>
    More Text
</request>
```

Mixed text has its uses, but is generally frowned upon.  The preferred approach would be to use an XML attribute as described  in your question:

```
<request sessionId="read-only">Get Price</request>
```

To see how JAXB can handle mixed text see the `@XmlMixed` annotation:

- http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/javax/xml/bind/annotation/XmlMixed.html

Comment: Excellent thank you! 

Now I wish JAXB, which is generally good at generating meaningful error messages, could mention `@XmlMixed` annotation in that message. :) On another hand, I should have read the manual first ;-)

Comment: Blaise, Would you be able to elaborate on using the @XmlMixed annotation to achieve the output described in the question?  I have the exact same requirements.  I have no control over what the output is, I just have to match it.  A 3rd party program accepts XML as an input and the format is mixed so my hands are tied...

Answer (score 1):

Is there anything wrong with making `commandId` an element as well? e.g.

```
<request>
    <commandId>Get Price</commandId>
    <sessionId>read-only</sessionId>
</request>
```

and

```
@XmlRootElement(name="request")
public class  Request {

    @XmlElement
    public String getCommandID() { return "Get Price"; };  
    // btw, why's this a constant?

    @XmlElement
    public String getSessionID() { return "read-only"; };  
    // and this too?

}
```

Comment: _// btw, why's this a constant?_ > I didn't mean to confuse, it's just for illustrative purposes. Thanks!